# Recognize namespaced symbol in a Clojure macro

Tags: clojure

I am working on a macro, `either` which does some code transformations, defined in the file `epicea.antivalue.core`. Among other things, it should recognize the use of the symbol `make` as if that symbol was bound in the namespace `epicea.antivalue.core`. But ideally, the symbol `make` should be unbound. My code is available here: https://github.com/jonasseglare/epicea-antivalue/tree/stackoverlow-question

To identify the symbol `make`, I here is some code from `epicea.antivalue.core`:

```
(def make ::make)

(defn evals-to-keyword [kwd]
  (fn [x]
    (try
      (and (symbol? x)
           (= kwd (eval x)))
      (catch Throwable e
        false))))

;; Function to test if we are referring to a symbol 'make' in the namespace of this file.
(def make-sym? (evals-to-keyword ::make))
```

but unfortunately, I need the line 
    (def make ::make)
in order for it to work.

My problem is reflected by the unit testing code in 
    epicea.antivalue.core-test.clj
which *currently fails*:

```
(ns epicea.antivalue.core-test
  (:import [epicea.antivalue AntivalueException])
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [epicea.tag.core :as tag]
            [epicea.antivalue.core :as av]))

(deftest contextual-make
  ;; The call to 'av/make' should only work inside the 'av/either' macro
  ;; These tests PASS
  (is (= 4 (av/either (av/make false 9 3) 4)))
  (is (= 9 (av/either (av/make true 9 3) 4)))

  ;; This test PASSES, as we would expect.
  (is (try
        (eval '(println epicea.antivalue.core/some-unbound-symbol))
        false
        (catch Throwable e
          true)))

  ;; But outside the 'av/either' macro, 'av/make' should be unbound.
  ;; This test FAILS, but I don't want it to fail. How can we achieve that?
  (is (try
        (eval '(println epicea.antivalue.core/make))
        false
        (catch Throwable e
          true))))
```

**So my question is**: How can I implement the function `make-sym?` without having the the symbol `make` defined in the `epicea.antivalue.core` namespace? In other words, how can I make the unit test pass, by only editing the source file `epicea.antivalue.core`?